# MySQL Trigger - timestamp hour between?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm after a mysql trigger that will set the column `peak` to 0 or 1 based on the `timestamp` hour between **08:01 & 23:59**.

Can anyone help?

example:-

```
userstats.timestamp = 2018-07-01 12:27:20
peak = 1
```

Comment: A trigger will fire on an insert, update or delete do you have such an event, if so what is it and can you publish what you have tried.

Comment: Remember that SO isn't a code writing service. Do some research on the syntax and use of triggers, give a try at writing one, then ask for help with whatever doesn't work.

Comment: Pls see the following meta discussion on how to improve your question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the `DATE_FORMAT` function to isolate the time component of your timestamp, e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM userstats
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%H:%i') BETWEEN '08:01' AND '23:59';
```

Your actual query may not look exactly like this, but this would seem to answer the crux of your question.